# vb.net ListBox select multiple items and pass into array in parent form

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am using this code to populate a listbox in vb.net

```
conn.Open()
        SQL = "select company from customer order by company ASC"
        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))
        End While
```

this code is run in a form named `customers`, i use `customers.show()` on my initial form (`form1`)

once items have been selected in the `customers` form, how can i pass all the values back to the parent form ready to process the data?

Comment: start by using instances of your forms, then just add a method to receive the values, a string array in this case probably,  you dont have any code showing what you have tried in this regard.

Comment: In addition to Plutonix's answer, you could start by putting this in Form1: `Friend SelectedBoxItems As New List(Of String)` or if you prefer `Friend SelectedBoxItems() As String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this help , but i'm not quite sure of what you want .
this code is passing the selected items to the "Form1" in some listbox :

```
  Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Some_Button_in_Customers_Form.Click
     For Each itm in Listbox1.SelectedItems
        Form1.Some_ListBox.Items.Add(itm)
     Loop
     'if you want to end form after passing customers UnHighlight next line
     'Me.Close()
  End Sub
```

and if you don't want to add a BUTTON to your Customers Form Use Next Code After your Code :

```
  Dim btn as New Button
  AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
  btn.PerformClick()
```

and Handler code will be without *"Handles Some_Button_in_Customers_Form.Click"* like this :

```
  Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     For Each itm in Listbox1.SelectedItems
        Form1.Some_ListBox.Items.Add(itm)
     Loop
     'if you want to end form after passing customers UnHighlight next line
     'Me.Close()
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SelectedItems` Property of ListBox1 , to get all the selected items collection , then you can use the cast extension method to convert this collection into a string enumerable then convert it into either list or array.

```
Public Function getSelectedItems()
      return ListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast(of String).Tolist()
End Function
```

then call this function from within your `Form1` using your `customers` form instance